# The POST request persisted in the MySQL but returns null

Tags: java

I wrote some Java wallet generation code and I use it for generating a crypto-currency wallet. The code is provided,

```
public synchronized WalletInfo generateAddress(GenerateWallet generateWallet) {

        final WalletInfo walletInfo = new WalletInfo();

        String walletName = generateWallet.getWalletName();

        String currencyName = generateWallet.getCurrencyName();

        WalletInfo walletInfoDb = iWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);

        if (walletInfoDb == null && genWalletMap.get(walletName) == null) {

            String currency = currencyName.toUpperCase();

            if (currency.equals("BITCOIN")) {

                final WalletManager walletManager = WalletManager.setupWallet(walletName);

                walletManager.addWalletSetupCompletedListener((wallet) -> {

                    Address address = wallet.currentReceiveAddress();
                    WalletInfo newWallet = createWalletInfo(walletName, currencyName, address.toString());

                    // set the properties of the walletInfo
                    walletInfo.setId(newWallet.getId());
                    walletInfo.setName(newWallet.getName());
                    walletInfo.setAddress(newWallet.getAddress());
                    walletInfo.setCurrency(newWallet.getCurrency());

                    walletMangersMap.put(newWallet.getId(), walletManager);
                    genWalletMap.remove(walletName);
                });

                genWalletMap.put(walletName, walletManager);
                return walletInfo;
            } else if (currency.equals("ETHEREUM")) {
                return walletInfo;
            } else {
                return walletInfo;
            }
        }

        return walletInfo;
    }
```

When I do a POST request using the cURL,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"walletName": "Florence8","currencyName":"Bitcoin"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/wallet/generateAddress
```

I get null is the return,

```
{
  "id" : null,
  "name" : null,
  "address" : null,
  "currency" : null
}
```

While the entity is generated and still persisted in the MySQL. I keep debugging and this is wired. The debugging doesn't follow top-to-bottom sequence of the code. The sequence of the debugging is like,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The point that I would like to make is if the code comes to this line 
`walletManager.addWalletSetupCompletedListener((wallet)`, then it should execute the operations inside.

Any suggestion how do I get the entity back after rightfully persisted in the database? I can provide more info if required

Update

As suggested in the answer, I use a `CountDownLatch` and solve the problem

```
public synchronized WalletInfo generateAddress(GenerateWallet generateWallet) {

        CountDownLatch finshedSetup = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // some code 
}
```

The output in the terminal,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running into a race condition. You're setting up a callback to fill in the `walletInfo`, but potentially returning `walletInfo` before the callback has executed.

Some type of promise or latch to wait on before returning could help. For example:

```
public synchronized WalletInfo generateAddress(GenerateWallet generateWallet) {

        final WalletInfo walletInfo = new WalletInfo();

        String walletName = generateWallet.getWalletName();

        String currencyName = generateWallet.getCurrencyName();

        WalletInfo walletInfoDb = iWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);

        if (walletInfoDb == null && genWalletMap.get(walletName) == null) {

            String currency = currencyName.toUpperCase();

            if (currency.equals("BITCOIN")) {

                final WalletManager walletManager = WalletManager.setupWallet(walletName);
                CountDownLatch finishedSetup = new CountDownLatch(1);

                walletManager.addWalletSetupCompletedListener((wallet) -> {

                    Address address = wallet.currentReceiveAddress();
                    WalletInfo newWallet = createWalletInfo(walletName, currencyName, address.toString());

                    // set the properties of the walletInfo
                    walletInfo.setId(newWallet.getId());
                    walletInfo.setName(newWallet.getName());
                    walletInfo.setAddress(newWallet.getAddress());
                    walletInfo.setCurrency(newWallet.getCurrency());

                    walletMangersMap.put(newWallet.getId(), walletManager);
                    genWalletMap.remove(walletName);
                    finshedSetup.countDown();
                });

                genWalletMap.put(walletName, walletManager);
                finishedSetup.await();
                return walletInfo;
            } else if (currency.equals("ETHEREUM")) {
                return walletInfo;
            } else {
                return walletInfo;
            }
        }

        return walletInfo;
    }
```

Comment: I have limited knowledge of the multi-threading. Would you please help me to solve it? I can deliver other parts of the code required.

Comment: @Artin updated with a countdown latch example. More reading on how latches work here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the update. Whats the `finishedSetup` method in the code? Can you provide an example? I will accept the as soon as I understand what is going on

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: `finishedSetup` is a new countdown latch that I instantiated with count 1. `await()` waits for the countdown to reach 0. `countDown()` decrements the count by 1.

Comment: It's a count. It's just waiting for some other thread to decrement the count (by calling `countDown()`). It is *not* time-based.